# Some shortcode doesn't work in admin-ajax

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I need to change content of the page throught ajax which contains some Visual composer shortcode and also another shortode [codespacing_progress_map] related plugin with same name. This shortode shows just like a normal text insted of map generated by shortcode output.
Actually even VC shortdes didn't work in ajax before but I found this trick to fix it:

```
if ( class_exists( 'WPBMap' ) && method_exists( 'WPBMap', 'addAllMappedShortcodes' ) ) {
   WPBMap::addAllMappedShortcodes();    
}
```

The code looks like this:

```
if ( shortcode_exists( 'codespacing_progress_map' ) ){} //this returns false!
echo apply_filters('the_content','[vc_column][vc_column_text][codespacing_progress_map][/vc_column_text][vc_column_text][/vc_column_text][/vc_column]');
```

Seems like shortcode don't exist althought plugin is artivated.